# How to use graphiql with express and graphql server with graphql-http?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I switched from express-graphql to graphql-http and the graphiql just stops working.

```
const express = require("express");
const {createHandler} = require("graphql-http/lib/use/express");
const schema = require("./schema/schema");

const app = express();

app.use("/graphql", createHandler({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
}));


app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Server is running on PORT 4000..."));
```

Answer (score 2):

`graphql-http` package does not provide an out-of-a-box GraphqQL Playground.

[Only GraphQL over HTTP](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-http#only-graphql-over-http) and this [issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-http/discussions/38#discussioncomment-4698804)

> This is the official GraphQL over HTTP spec reference implementation and as such follows the specification strictly without any additional features (like playgrounds or GUIs, file uploads, @stream/@defer directives and subscriptions).

You can use [graphql-playground-middleware-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-playground-middleware-express) to expose an endpoint for the GraphQL Playground.

E.g.

```
const express = require('express');
const { createHandler } = require('graphql-http/lib/use/express');
const expressPlayground =
  require('graphql-playground-middleware-express').default;
const { GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString } = require('graphql');

/**
 * Construct a GraphQL schema and define the necessary resolvers.
 *
 * type Query {
 *   hello: String
 * }
 */
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
      hello: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve: () => 'world',
      },
    },
  }),
});

const app = express();

app.all('/graphql', createHandler({ schema }));
app.get('/playground', expressPlayground({ endpoint: '/graphql' }));

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server is running on PORT 4000...'));
```

Access `https://so76735343-0n0m--4000--c53ab388.local-corp.webcontainer.io/playground` endpoint, you will see GraphQL playground UI.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76735343?file=index.js)